# PowerShell Don't wait for parameter

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have a function to move files that are older than x days from one directory to another. This works flawlessly with both available parameter sets. When I run the function manually and I forget the `Quantity`, PowerShell is prompting me to fill it in. This is how it should be.

However, when I run my script which addresses these parameters and I forget the `Quantity` in my input CSV-file, it's not throwing an error for the missing `Quantity`. How can I force it to throw an error when it's not provided? So it doesn't wait or prompt me to fill it in...

**Syntax:**

```
    Move-Files [-Source] <String> [[-Destination] <String>] [-Structure <String>] [-WhatIf ] [-Confirm ] [<CommonParameters>]

    Move-Files [-Source] <String> [[-Destination] <String>] [-Structure <String>] -OlderThan <String> -Quantity <Int32> [-WhatIf ] [-Confirm ] [<CommonParameters>]
```

**Parameters:**

```
Function Move-Files {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True,DefaultParameterSetName='A')]
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ParameterSetName='A')]
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ParameterSetName='B')]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [String]$Source,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1,ParameterSetName='A')]
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=1,ParameterSetName='B')]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Container})]
        [String]$Destination = $Source,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='A')]
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='B')]
        [ValidateSet('Year','Year\Month','Year-Month')]
        [String]$Structure = 'Year-Month',
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='B')]
        [ValidateSet('Day','Month','Year')]
        [String]$OlderThan,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='B')]
        [Int]$Quantity
    )
```

**Line in my script:**

```
Move-Files -Source 'S:\Test' -Destination 'S:\Target' -Structure Year\Month -OlderThan Day
```

This is used in a `foreach` loop like so:

```
$File | ForEach-Object {

    $MoveParams = @{
        Source = $_.Source
        Destination = $_.Destination
        Structure = $_.Structure
        OlderThan = $_.OlderThan
        Quantity = $_.Quantity
    }

Try {
   Move-Files @MoveParams
}
Catch {
   "Error reported"
}
```

**Workaround:**

```
$MoveParams.Values | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -eq $null) {
        Write-Error "Incomplete parameters:`n $($MoveParams | Format-Table | Out-String)"
        Return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```powershell
[Int]$Quantity(Mandatory=$true)
```

Comment: Thank you Raf, but `Quantity` is only `Mandatory` in `ParameterSetName = B`, when `OlderThan` is selected. So it's not always mandatory. Maybe there's a way for the script that I can tell it to use `ParameterSetName = B`?

Comment: If you are reading in from CSV, then every PSObject you pass in will have a Quantity property, even if it's null. As such it will always be looking at parameter set B, but you will be passing in a null value. Try calling your function with -debug to get more information out.